# Is this large exhaust fan in bathroom installed right?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, shower, exhaust-fan

[image]

This window is right where the shower is. Can't have any fan but there. It opens upwards. Hired someone to install this fan but his idea was what you see in the picture. It's not sitting flush on the window and not connected to any outlet. Also the glass doesn't hold it.

What's the best way to getting that fan on the window if at all? I don't need a window that opens when I have a fan, just that the fan is stable.

Comment: To me, that looks like a very poor job. If the fan can't be mounted and permanently wired in the wall it would be better mounted in the middle of the glass using a glass circle cutter and a window mounting kit.

Comment: I would be worried about it potentially falling into the shower and being an electrocution hazard. Is it wired to a GFCI receptacle or breaker?

Comment: There is no ground here, but its not yet wired. I will rely that to the guy responsible. I ask because they only take instructions, if you dont tell them how to do it, you end up with something like in this picture.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick can i just ask why its better to have it in middle of the glass? I dont know about window mounting kit, what they have done is glued it to the glass, i think hot glue by the looks of it.

Comment: @Altoban: Personally I feel it [looks better](http://verifieddesigns.com/i/2016/01/exhaust-fan-bathroom-window-on-frosted-glass-window-615x416.jpg) than what you have. But of course that is just subjective, other people will disagree I'm sure.

Comment: its certainly sticking out, not flush on the window, they insist on doing that thinking the window wouldnt hold that fan by itself.